# Tv show about kids traveling parallel worlds to find their dad

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, science-fiction

What is the TV show that a father is a scientist or something who invents a machine to travel parallel worlds but traps in somewhere, leaving just a mystery message to their kids.

And the kids (one kid is in a wheelchair as I recall) figure out their lost father is trapped in the worlds. They take turns and travel each world one at a time to find their father. These worlds are full of magic, witches and creatures. One time they travel to an Egypt land too.

The wheel-chaired kid can walk in these world. When one is in one of these worlds can communicate with the kid in the real world and can be seen from the computer screen. These are the things I remember.

Does anyone know the name of this show? The show is a bit old I guess and must have aired long before 2004. The language was English.

Comment: Hi, DragNa; welcome to Movies&TV. Can you tell/guess the country of origin and the time the show was aired?

Comment: The language was English is all I know. The show must have aired long before 2004. Sorry I couldn't be much of a help on that. But the show was super cool. I loved to watch it as a kid those days.

Comment: Jim Henson's Slider Babies?

Comment: There was also a movie like this recently wherein a building was used to jump between the parallel universes

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sounds like [MythQuest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MythQuest) from 2001.

> MythQuest is a Canadian television series that originally aired on PBS in 2001. It stars Meredith Henderson and Christopher Jacot as Cleo and Alex Bellows, two teens whose father Matt disappears into the Cyber Museum, a computer program that, as they discover, allows them to travel into myths by touching an artifact on the screen.

The sister is in a wheelchair and they travel to the places you described. Here are the opening credits:

Comment: That's a pretty obscure series, very good job finding it!